# html canvas not resizing properly after screen rotation on mobile website

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas, screen

I am working on an html canvas for the frist time I am using gatsby to develop my project

my problem is that my html canvas is cut when there is a rotation I seem to have a problem with the width and the height but I can't seem to understand what the problem is

here are some pictures of the problem :

[without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANEBP.png)

[after the first rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzesT.png)

[after the second rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytlvb.png)

and here is the part of my code where I handle my canvas

Thank you for your help I am just a beginner so I am sorry if my code is not really clean

```
function MainScratch ()  {
let canvas = useRef(null)
function getSize() {
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'

    if (isBrowser) return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
    }
    else return {
        width: 5,
        height: 5,
    }
}

const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize)

useEffect (() => {

    function handleResize() {
        setWindowSize(getSize())
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)

},[]);

useEffect(() => {
    let renderingElement = canvas.current
    let drawingElement = renderingElement.cloneNode()

    let drawingCtx = drawingElement.getContext('2d')
    let renderingCtx = renderingElement.getContext('2d')


    let lastX
    let lastY

    let moving = false

    renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"       
    renderingCtx.fillStyle = '#000000'
    renderingCtx.fillRect(0, 0, windowSize.width, windowSize.height)

    function reload()
    {
        renderingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, drawingElement.width, drawingElement.height);
        drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, renderingElement.width, renderingElement.height);
        renderingCtx.fillRect(0, 0, windowSize.width, windowSize.height)
        
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", reload)
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", reload)

    renderingElement.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
        moving = true
        lastX = e.touches[0].pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft
        lastY = e.touches[0].pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    renderingElement.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
        moving = false
        lastX = e.lastX - renderingElement.offsetLeft
        lastY = e.lastY - renderingElement.offsetTop
    })

    renderingElement.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
        moving = true
        if (moving) {
            drawingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"
            renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"
            let currentX = e.touches[0].pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft
            let currentY = e.touches[0].pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop
            drawingCtx.beginPath();
            drawingCtx.lineJoin = "round"
            drawingCtx.moveTo(lastX, lastY)
            drawingCtx.lineTo(currentX, currentY)
            drawingCtx.closePath()
            drawingCtx.lineWidth = 80;
            drawingCtx.stroke()
            lastX = currentX
            lastY = currentY
            renderingCtx.drawImage(drawingElement, 0, 0)
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}, []);

return (
    <Banner>
        <Canvas
            id="canvas"
            height={windowSize.height}
            width={windowSize.width}
            ref={canvas}
        />
    </Banner>
)
```

Comment: Looks like you're never changing the size of `drawingElement`. Move `let drawingElement = renderingElement.cloneNode();` and `let drawingCtx = drawingElement.getContext("2d");` to the start of the `reload` function.

Comment: You also cannot rely on `windowSize` in the event listeners because updating state is asynchronous, so when your `reload` function runs `renderingCtx.fillRect(0, 0, windowSize.width, windowSize.height);` windowSize still has the old values.